# converting string into a list of tuple_ python

Tags: python, json

I scraped some data from a website then saved it in a json file.
When I called the json file in another code it became a long long string like this

```
'[[" Up to 300 g ", " 900 yen ", " 1,200 yen ", " 1,500 yen ", " 1,700 yen "], [" Up to 500 g ", " 1,100 yen ", " 1,500 yen ", " 1,800 yen ", " 2,100 yen "], [" Up to 600 g ", " 1,240 yen ", " 1,680 yen ", " 2,000 yen ", " 2,440 yen "], [" Up to 700 g ", " 1,380 yen ", " 1,860 yen ", " 2,200 yen ", " 2,780 yen "] ................
```

How can I convert the whole thing into a list of tuple

```
[ 
  [" Up to 300 g ", " 900 yen ", " 1,200 yen ", " 1,500 yen ", " 1,700 yen "],
  [" Up to 500 g ", " 1,100 yen ", " 1,500 yen ", " 1,800 yen ", " 2,100 yen "],
  [" Up to 600 g ", " 1,240 yen ", " 1,680 yen ", " 2,000 yen ", " 2,440 yen "],
  ....
  ....
]
```

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Why don't you refer to the `json` doc:http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import json

with open('json_file') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('[[" Up to 300 g ", " 900 yen ", " 1,200 yen ", " 1,500 yen ", " 1,700 yen "], [" Up to 500 g ", " 1,100 yen ", " 1,500 yen ", " 1,800 yen ", " 2,100 yen "]]')
[[' Up to 300 g ', ' 900 yen ', ' 1,200 yen ', ' 1,500 yen ', ' 1,700 yen '], [' Up to 500 g ', ' 1,100 yen ', ' 1,500 yen ', ' 1,800 yen ', ' 2,100 yen ']]
```